# Enabling and disabling global-company-mode without hook

Tags: company-mode

I want to be able to enable and disable `global-company-mode` by calling elisp functions in my init file.

Could I use `(global-company-mode 1)` to enable and `(global-company-mode -1)` to disable

Does this mean that I can do (global-company-mode 1) and (global-company-mode -1) without using the hook way `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)`.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid the hook.

Comment: `global-company-mode` is just a normal elisp function, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to invoke `(global-company-mode 1)` from Elisp.

Comment: You would generally *NOT* invoke a global minor mode from a hook. A global minor mode is designed to turn on the corresponding minor mode globally. There is no point doing that from a hook: hooks are designed to enable minor modes (and other things) *selectively*, e.g. by turning it on for all buffers of a particular major mode.

Comment: `company-mode` should be revisited because the documentation of company states that to have `company-mode` in all buffers, the following must be added to your init file:
`(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? I said "generally" because there are exceptions. But I really should have qualified it more: you wouldn't  invoke a global minor mode from a *mode* hook. There are other hooks (e.g. the `after-init-hook`)  that are meant for different purposes.

Comment: The reason for using `after-init-hook` is to avoid the initialization messing around with the setting. If you don't mess around with the setting during initialization, then you can invoke the global mode directly: you don't need the hook. But doing it in the hook ensures that no matter how you change your init file later (e.g. disable the global mode), it will still be turned on at the end. Whether that's good or bad depends on your POV.

Comment: I just realized that you had specified `after-init-hook` in your question, which I had missed originally, so I went off on a tangent. Apologies for my mistake.